# A little baffled on DBMigrations with Code First and EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a project that I created and enabled Migrations on.  It created it with 4.3 so I think it is the latest.  I have some code in the constructor of the context that executes the update (see code below) and that seems to work everytime I add something like a nullable string column or do something that does not change the database in non consistent manner.  My scenario is I change my model, and when I watch sql trace, it does the alter columns for me automatically.

My question is I want to do the "up" and "down" methods but am confused on when they run.  That is say I'm on version 1 now, I put some code in my "up" method to add a column, then later when I want to go to version 3, how does it know which "up" method to call?

Confused.  -Peter

```
namespace MigrationsAutomaticDemo.Migrations
{
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class AddBlogRating : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("Blogs", "Rating", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 3));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("Blogs", "Rating");
    }
}
}
```

,

```
    public SiteDB()
    {
        UpdateDatabase();
    }

    // http://joshmouch.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-executing-migrations-using-code-not-powershell-commands/
    public static int IsMigrating = 0;
    private static void UpdateDatabase()
    {
        if (0 == Interlocked.Exchange(ref IsMigrating, 1))
        {
            // Manually creating configuration: 
            var migratorConfig = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<SiteDB>(); 
            migratorConfig.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

            // Using configuration defined in project: 
            //var migratorConfig = new DbMigrationsConfiguration();

            // 3 
            //var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Settings()); 
            var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(migratorConfig);
            dbMigrator.Update();

            Interlocked.Exchange(ref IsMigrating, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the automatic migration in the migration configuration, then you don't need to specify the target migration. The migrator will automatically scaffold the changes based on the snapshot of current context and target database.

```
var migratorConfig = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<SiteDB>();
migratorConfig.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
```

In your case, you want to upgrade your database by using specific migration. All you need to do is mentioning explicitly which migration to upgrade.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update("201204250656061_AddBlogRatingVersion2");
migrator.Update("201204250656061_AddBlogRatingVersion3");
migrator.Update("201204250656061_AddBlogRatingVersionX");
```

Comment: I still don't see where I put the different UP's and DOWN's for each step.  That is, I may need to do my own sql on each step to make the migrations work. Things like setting foreign keys to correct values for data that is already populated.

Comment: Hi Peter, you need to generate each migration for each step.

For example:
The 201204250656061_AddBlogRatingVersion2 is to add Rating and VisitCount column.
The 201204250656061_AddBlogRatingVersion3 is to add LastVisited and LastUpdated column.

The migration target is an id that is generated by the tool [package manager console](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: sorry for being thick, but I'm still confused.  If there are updates that can not be generated automatically, how do I code those so they stick to a certain version to up or version to down?  Also, do you have to use package manager for this?

Comment: You can modify the generated migration class, there're some methods from [System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) that you can use (you can even put sql query by using Sql method).  
If you want to do versioning for the application, you need to generate each migration by using the package manager. If not, you can just use automatic migration by code to update to the latest version.  
'new DbMigrator(new DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext> { AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true }).Update();'